# Grunt-Sass How to prevent uncompression of CSS

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, node-sass

I'm using [GRUNT-SASS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass) for my project and I'm using a minified version of normalize.css and have it on partials named _reset.scss. My problem is, GRUNT-CSS converting it into uncompressed/beautified version when saved (in .css file). I want to saved it to .css as compressed when I add it as compressed in partial SCSS file. Is there a way to do it?

Here is my grunfile.js:

```
// The "wrapper" function
module.exports = function(grunt) {

const sass = require('node-sass');

// Project and task c onfiguration
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    /**
     * Grunt Sass
     * Compile Sass to CSS using node-sass
     * https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass
     */
    sass: {
        options: {
                implementation: sass,
                sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
                files: {
                        'style.css' : 'assets/scss/main.scss'
                }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Grunt Contrib Watch
     * Monitor files and execute tasks
     * https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-watch
     */
    watch: {
        sass: {
            files: [
                'assets/scss/*.scss'
            ],
            tasks: [
                'sass'
            ]               
        }
    }


});

// Load all grunt tasks matching the ['grunt-*', '@*/grunt-*'] patterns
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); 

// Custom tasks
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

Comment: I don't see any options set to output a compressed CSS file.

Comment: @disinfor I reviewed the documentation and found out that there is a way to set the output file to get compressed by adding `outputStyle: 'compressed'` to the sass options but I don't want to get the whole css file to be compressed. I only want part of it like for example, the code inside my _resets.scss partial file, the rest will be in compact. I'm hoping there's a way to do that.

Comment: I don't believe you can split up the output style per partial. Why not compress the whole file? What issue are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @disinfor I'm creating theme for WordPress and one of the reason is that WordPress requires header comments, and using `outputStyle: 'compressed'` removed that comments when compressed. I also just like to compressed the part of my .CSS that doesn't need changes like resets.

Comment: You can avoid that by using the `style.css` file for the theme information and nothing else - which is what you should do. And you should always compress your CSS if you can to help with page speed metrics - (I'm a full-time WP dev as well)

Comment: @disinfor Thank you the tips! GOD BLESS you!